# how to sum digits in a multi-digit number Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, digits

I wonder how to sum digits for a multi-digit number in Matlab.

For example 1241= 1+2+4+1 = 8

Comment: There must be plenty of Matlab tutorials available online you can read. Ask here about the parts you don't understand...

Answer (score 5):

String-based answer:

```
>> n = 1241;
>> sum(int2str(n)-48)

ans =

     8
```

The number is first converted to a string representation using [`int2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int2str.html?refresh=true), then the ASCII code for `'0'` (i.e. 48) is subtracted from the ASCII code for each element of the string, producing a numeric vector. This is then summed to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
A  = 35356536576821;
A  = abs(A);
xp = ceil(log10(A)):-1:1;

while ~isscalar(xp)
    A  = sum(fix(mod(A,10.^xp)./10.^[xp(2:end) 0]));
    xp = ceil(log10(A)):-1:1;
end
```

this is the numeric approach

Answer (score 1):

This one is the solution is character approach:

```
A = '35356536576821';
A = char(regexp(A,'\d+','match'));
while ~isscalar(A)
    A = num2str(sum(A - '0'));
end
```

Both, first take the absolute number (strip the minus) then: the numeric one counts with `log10()` how many digits a number has and through modulus and divisions extracts the digits which are summed, while the char approach convert to numeric digits with implicit conversion of  `- '0'`, sums and converts back to string again.

Answer (score 1):

Another all-arithmetic approach:

```
n = 1241;                   %// input
s = 0;                      %// initiallize output
while n>0                   %// while there is some digit left
    s = s + mod(n-1,10)+1;  %// sum rightmost digit
    n = floor(n/10);        %// remove that digit
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Youcan use this code

```
sum(int2str(n)-48)
```

where n, is your input number.